# Swift Combine: Unknown attribute 'ObservedObject' error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, combine

I have the following implementation:

```
final class Article: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var title: String!
    @NSManaged var summary: String!
}

class someOtherClass {
    @ObservedObject var article: Article?
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Unknown attribute 'ObservedObject'
```

[image]

My question is how can I fix this error? or any of you knows a work around.

Comment: `@ObservedObject` belongs to `SwiftUI` not `Combine`

Comment: There is any alternative for Combine? @vadian

Comment: It's unclear what you are going to accomplish. And never declare `@NSManaged` properties as IUO.

Comment: @vadian I want to observe and react with any changes in my core data stack

Comment: Please read https://www.avanderlee.com/combine/nsmanagedobject-observe-changes-core-data/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a class in another class you have to create a reference of it. You would only use observedobject, environmentobject, etc. in your view.